# Can I draw to a panel on a transparent WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, transparency

After seeing that drawing to the desktop is extremely messy, I decided just to research around. I figured out that many people suggest creating a transparent WinForm that is the size of the screen and smacking a panel on there and using that to draw graphics. So I tested it out but ran into many errors. At first, my second form (Form2) wouldn't show, so I had to put it into another thread and put `Form2.ShowDialog();` on that thread. After I got that problem out of the way, I actually drew to the panel. Now my form will never show, but I can see it running on my taskbar. Everytime I try to make it the focused window, it never works, and whenever I hover the task I can see the graphics being created. My question is, is it possible to draw to a panel on a transparent WinForm and make it visible? Here's the code I used, it's mostly for looking for errors (drawing the states and stuff).

```
void Draw()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SolidBrush redpen = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
            PointF point = new PointF(700, 150);
            Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

            g.DrawString(Main.state.ToString(), font, redpen, point);

            Main.beginTime.Stop();
            Main.TimeRan = Main.beginTime.Elapsed;

            string amountOfTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", Main.TimeRan.Hours, Main.TimeRan.Minutes, Main.TimeRan.Seconds, Main.TimeRan.Milliseconds / 10);
            point = new PointF(700, 200);

            g.DrawString(amountOfTime, font, redpen, point);

            Thread.Sleep(10);
            panel1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Draw();
    }
```

Somewhere in my main class

```
    // In a method
    Thread F2T = new Thread(FormHandlers);
    F2T.Start();

    private void FormHandlers()
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Opacity = 0.00;
        Form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Edit: After some testing, I noticed that with the decrease of opacity the letter's opacity decreases as well, can I make it so the panel is transparent but the string I'm drawing to draw inside of it is not?

Comment: what do you want to draw on the form?

Comment: My program is state-based, so the current state it is on and the amount of time ran

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to draw a message on a transparent child form? if that, I think you could do as follow: because the `form.Opacity =0.00` makes all the controls in it be transparent, so we can't see anything. Another way, we use `form.TransparencyKey` to get that. code like this:

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //hide the border of form
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        //set the TransparencyKey the same as the back color
        this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
    }

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush redpen = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
        PointF point = new PointF(400, 150);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        string state = "running";
        g.DrawString(state, font, redpen, point);
        string amountOfTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", 1, 2, 3, 11111 / 10);
        PointF point2 = new PointF(500, 150);
        g.DrawString(amountOfTime, font, redpen, point2);

        //base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

by the way, you want to show message in a child form, I don't prefer to use multi-threading, you just invoke the Form2 in `Show()` not in `ShowDialog()`, and set `Form2.TopMost=True`, than you can operate your main form as well. try it.
my result is bellow:
[image: result of transparent drawing.]

Comment: can you paste your current code? and describe your problem, I will help you fix it. if you want to give more details, send mail: maxleaf_1999@126.com